# How to move the sprite(vehicles ) on slope image in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I m developing one game in cocos2d but i have one doubt, in this game i have one background and above that i want to add one slope image and i want to move the sprite(vehicles) on that slope randomly just like this game i m giving the link of one game, please suggest me how i can implement just like this video, I also want to make the game just like this.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMJFRd3bBhw

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

One option is using a path and make the sprites follow that path, define that path for each terrain. Another option is using a physics engine, you can do that using the engine itself (i think).

Comment: but some part i have did in cocos2d can i implement the physic engine in cocos2d and i dont have any idea about physics engine...will you please give any sample code or tutorial.

Comment: You can use box2D or chipmunk with cocos2d. For tutorials, check out Ray Wenderlich's: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials (under Game Physics).

Comment: Yep, ray tutorials are great.